Is there any way to preview images in compressed files (zip, rar, 7z, ...)?
I want to preview photos in compressed files without decompressing the files
Currently, for zip files, I use ZipFile and ZipEntry to view them, but they only work with zip files.
So I continue to use another library, 7-Zip-JBinding.
I got some data, but I don't know how to display the image. Here is the code that uses that library:
private suspend fun checkFileZip(filePath: String): MutableList<PhotoModel> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val list: MutableList<PhotoModel> = mutableListOf()
        runCatching {
            val randomAccessFile = RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r")
            val randomAccessFileStream = RandomAccessFileInStream(randomAccessFile)
            val inArchive = SevenZip.openInArchive(null, randomAccessFileStream)

            inArchive.simpleInterface.archiveItems?.forEach { item ->
                if (!item.isFolder) {
                    if (item.path.contains(".jpg") || item.path.contains(".png")) {
                        if (item.size > 10000) {
                            val photoModel = PhotoModel(
                                "$filePath/${item.path.toFolderName()}",
                                resolution = "",
                                sizePhoto = item.size,
                                lastModifiedPhoto = item.lastWriteTime.time,
                                isFileInApk = true,
                                zipFileString = filePath,
                                zipEntryString = filePath,
                            )
                            addPhotoModel(photoModel)
                            list.add(photoModel)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onFailure {
            Log.d("error", "$filePath - ${it.message}")
        }
        return@withContext list
    }
}

I want to know how to preview image files contained in compressed files.

That's a matter for whatever software is using for viewing them - so would be entirely dependent on what the user has installed

Essentially no.  @g00se says it is dependent on the software... there could be some software that reads the zipped files, but in the end it is going to decompress the images.
I know this is not your question, but if you want to avoid decompressing the files (and even transferring them to the client), then you could have a server process that:

decompresses the images
resizes them to a controlled preview size
makes them available via another endpoint, maybe one that returns the image/jpeg etc content directly

